# NSArray [UIImage setContentMode:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I want to put defaults images if i don't have images from url feed.

```
if(![[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] valueForKey:@"url"]==nil)
{  NSNumber *numberOfKeyInstances = [stories valueForKey:@"key"];
    imageArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],nil];

    int  randomNumber_ = rand ()%19;
    UIImage *image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imag=image;




}
else{
    if (![[[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] valueForKey:@"url"] isEqualToString:@""]) {


        [cell.imag setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey:@"url"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Alb.png"]];

    }



}
```

This is my code, but i get `[UIImage setContentMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f908c1dcce0'`

How can i solved?

Comment: What is `cell.imag` ?

Comment: Anywhere r u setting contentMode to cell.image..At XIB or through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `imageArray` is initialised with only one image. So calling `[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is a problem. You dont need an image array for that. Secondly, the argument inside the first `if` statement doesn't look right.

Also, as @midhun-mp Pointed out, u should be probably using `cell.imag.image`.

Try this :

```
if([[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] valueForKey:@"url"] == nil)
{  
   cell.imag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
}
else if ([[[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] valueForKey:@"url"] isEqualToString:@""]) 
{
   cell.imag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
}
else
{
   //SET YOUR IMAGE HERE
}
```

Comment: and what if i want to have an array with 20 images?

Comment: @nicoleSD. yeah if you want 20 images you can definitely use `NSArray`. In the code you posted above though, you only inserted one image into your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
UIImage *image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `cell.imag` is a `UIImageView` not `UIImage` property.

So you need to change:

```
cell.imag=image;
```

to

```
cell.imag.image = image;
```